# Is there any grammar parseable by LALR(1) but not LR(1)?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser - as far as I understand, LALR(1) is a simplified version of LR(1), aiming to achieve a greater parsing performance at the expense of reduced power. So, IIUC, LALR(1) is a strict subset of LR(1): each grammar parseable by LALR(1) is parseable by LR(1), but not the other way around.

I'm surprised because it seems I've managed to create a grammar for which this tool: https://mdaines.github.io/grammophone/ says it *is not* LR(1) but *is* LALR(1) .

Therefore: Am I mistaken in my belief that LALR(1) is a strict subset of LR(1)? Or is Grammophone buggy and unreliable?

Comment: "I've managed to create a grammar." Can you include your grammar in the question?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Sadly, nope.

Comment: Grammophone is unreliable, sadly. Bison has a canonical-lr mode, which is reliable afaik.